# Summing data in rows based on horizontal and vertical criteria

Tags: arrays, excel, sum, formula, criteria

I have a dataset in the below format:

```
           Date 1   Date 1   Date 1  Date 2   Date 2   Date 3   Date 3
Product 1    10       20       10      5       10       20       30
Product 2    5        5        10      10      10       5        30
Product 3    30       10       5       10      30       30       40
Product 4    5        10       10      20      5        10       20
```

and I am trying to sum the sales of the products by the date, to create the below:

```
           Date 1   Date 2   Date 3  
Product 1    40       15       50            
Product 3    45       40       70       
Product 4    25       25       30 
Product 2    20       20       35
```

The products in the second table will often be in a different order, so a simple `SUMIF` will not suffice.

I've attempted a combination of `SUM`, `INDEX` and `MATCH`, as well as `SUM` with nested `IF` function, but no amount of Googling or trial and error is getting me there. I keep just bringing back the values in one cell, but not managing to sum.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is your post about programming in Excel (i.e, you're using a language such as VBA on your spreadsheet) or general Excel help? If your question is a general Excel help question, it would probably be a better fit for Supper User. See the [Excel tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) for more details about this.

Comment: Thanks! This is just a general Excel question (I think, unless it's going to take some VBA to solve it). I'll take a look.

Comment: I didn't realise I was jumping into such a minefield. I thought I'd sign up as on top of 'general Excel' I also use VBA, HTML, CSS & JS so thought SO might be a bit of a one stop shop for any questions I might have!

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for pointing that out. Do you if it would be possible to include that guidance on the Excel tag?

Comment: @pnuts, Thank you for the additional question. You seem to care about this much more than I do. I was looking at this single question and read the Excel tag, which says _."..General help regarding MS Excel for single worksheet functions is available at Super User..."_. As you have noted, the Excel tag description is contentious topic. I would suggest you raise your question on meta to make your point about needed clarification for the Excel tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following setup:

[image]

I used the following formula

```
=SUMIF($B$1:$H$1,B$10,INDIRECT("$B" & MATCH($A11,$A$1:$A$5,0) & ":$H" &MATCH($A11,$A$1:$A$5,0)))
```

To get what was wanted.  I put the formula in B11 and then copied across and Down